# add image in copyright section of footer

Tags: css, footer

I'm using betheme theme in wordpress.
In theme options, there's a box for copyright message. I wanted to try something different with it, so I linked an image to my own website to show the site creator.

Challenge I have is that the image won't sit in line with the rest of the text.

Can anyone help me out?

Here's my code:

`© 2018 Grandeur Catering. All Rights Reserved | Powered by [image src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/nanasarts.png" link="https://abcd.com" target="" align="right" position="absolute" top="-20px" border="0"]`

Snapshot looks like this:
https://extraimage.net/image/sCcK

Comment: I would assume it's the top parameter with the -20px, you are basically saying you want to push that image down 20 pixels. Try removing it and see what happens

Comment: Thanks for help. I had tried your suggestion even before I posted this. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: i later found a solution using html blocks. best thing that ever happened to me since slice bread